# BehaviorSubject issue, next() not working

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to use an angular service to store and communicate data through observable.

Here is my service

```
public _currentLegal = new BehaviorSubject({
  name: 'init',
  _id: 'init',
  country: 'init',
  city: 'init',
});
readonly currentLegal$ = this._currentLegal.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

setCurrentLegal(legal) {
  const legaltest = {
    name: 'test',
    _id: 'test',
    country: 'test',
    city: 'test',
  }
console.log('emitting next value from', legal.name)
this._currentLegal.next({ ...legaltest });
}
```

I got a component that call setCurrentLegal, the console.log is triggered and correct. I then navigate to another component which subscribe to the currentLegal$ observable and the value is still the same (init) !

I tried accessing the value directly by setting public type and using getValue(), same.
I tried duplicating the object as to not pass a reference, did not change anything.

Here is my subscripting component ngOnInit :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.legalToUpdate = this.legalService.currentLegal$.subscribe((legal) => {
    console.log(legal)
  })
}
```

What's wrong here ?
Thanks

Comment: What is the relation of the two component that do not share the state of the service? It seems that there is new instance of the service for each component. PS: You can just do `currentLegal$: Observable<yourType> = this.currentLegal` and also you might want to use `ReplaySubject` if initial value is not wanted and `.getValue` is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this behavior because you use it in different modules and it is created a different instances.

Put your service to be provide in root:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LegalService implements HttpInterceptor { }
```

Comment: yeah i'm alerady using the providedIn: 'root' :s 
And i only provide this service in one of my modules

Comment: @Julien FEGER put console.log under constructor to see how many instances are created

Comment: yeah you were right I removed it from my module providers since it was providedIn root by default. Thanks